# Why is dmesg called dmesg?

Tags: history, command, dmesg

Is there any explanation/history behind the name of the command `dmesg` (which prints out some kernel messages)?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I think it stands for *"diagnostic messages"*, as per the [older](http://man.cat-v.org/unix_8th/8/dmesg)<sup>1</sup> man page (referenced [here](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/sbin/dmesg/dmesg.8?r1=47462&r2=47461&pathrev=47462) too).

```
dmesg - system diagnostic messages
Dmesg looks in a system buffer for recent kernel diagnostic messages and reproduces them on the standard output
```

One of the oldest references appears to be a [man page](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/sbin/dmesg/dmesg.8?revision=18860&view=markup&pathrev=28297) revision by [Kirk McKusick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshall_Kirk_McKusick)  dating back from 1985.

---

<sup>1: the link doesn't always work - no idea why... I'm attaching a screenshot though you should still be able to access the page via Google's cache.</sup>

[image: man page for dmesg(8) listing "dmesg - system diagnostic messages" as the NAME]

Comment: How to choose of the two the answer that will be accepted?.. I believe it should be the answer with a (verified) reference going to an earlier time in history. 1980 from the other answer is better than 1985 from this one, but it remains without a material source yet.

Comment: That's how I see it: 1. OSX man page stating "The dmesg command appeared in 4.0BSD" doesn't mean OSX devs used the original `dmesg` description for their OSX man page. 2. Regardless of whether `dmesg` prints, collects or displays messages, we're still talking about _kernel diagnostic messages_, no matter how you [phrase](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E22985_01/html/E22986/z4000ca11330020.html) that. It is about **what** `dmesg` outputs, not about the meanings of _output_ (print, display etc). Anyway, it's your question so feel free to accept the answer that you consider the best.

Comment: AFAICT the command first appeared in the [7th Unix release](http://www.tuhs.org/Archive/PDP-11/Trees/V7/usr/src/cmd/), which gets you back to 1979, no man page, and the source references neither "diagnostic" nor "debug". The v8 man page in your first link is probably the best.

Comment: The man page synopsis  in 3BSD (1979) has: _"dmesg - collect system diagnostic messages to form error log"_

Answer (score 18):

I think the `dmesg` command just stands for *display messages*. [The FreeBSD manpages](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?dmesg) seem to share this view:

> dmesg -- display the system message buffer

Comment: I see, tank you! The Linux manpage is not so "explanatory": "dmesg - print or control the kernel ring buffer"

Comment: OS X shares this idea, with both "dmesg -- display the system message buffer" as well as "The dmesg command appeared in 4.0BSD." Unfortunately my Google-fu is failing - seems difficult to find source for 4.0 BSD these days...but that traces back to 1980, so 5 years earlier than referenced in the other answer.

Comment: @MarkGlossop Thanks for mentioning these bits of history! How to choose of the two the answer that will be accepted?.. I believe it should be the answer with a (verified) reference going to an earlier time in history. 1980 from your comments is better than 1985 from the other answer, but it remains without a material source yet.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmesg), `dmesg` is "*display message* or *driver message*"

Comment: Why was this down-voted?

Comment: @igal Related duplicate: [What does the 'd' mean in “dmesg”?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/340715/125388), which hinted that definition from Wikipedia is purely informational.