# What does the 'd' mean in "dmesg"?

Tags: history, dmesg

What is the origin of the letter `d` in `dmesg`?

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmesg):

> dmesg (display message or driver message)

No reference are given for this assertion - it could just as well be "debug message".

What is the etymology of `dmesg`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No reference are given for this assertion - it could just as well be "debug message".

Not all the messages are for debugging. Some are purely informational. From the `dmesg` manual page (emphasis added):

> The default action is to **d**isplay all **mes**sa**g**es from the kernel ring buffer.

**Update**: Alternatively, **d** is from "diagnostic". See: [Why is dmesg called dmesg?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76484/why-is-dmesg-called-dmesg).